# transparent image is giving a white background

Tags: css, image, javafx

I have downloaded a transparent image to apply on a button but it is giving a white background while applying with css in javafx.

[image: This image]

Comment: a jpg image can never be transparent

Comment: so, which type of image is transparent?

Comment: `.png`. You could also use a [`SVGPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/shape/SVGPath.html) as `graphic` for the `Button` and design the path in a svg image editor. This would allow you scale the path without rasterisation issues (svg is not supported as image though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone on this post said: **.png** and **.svg** image has transprent suport. The **.gif** type has that option too, maybe this site could help you: https://www.flaticon.com/
Just remember to see the license of the image.

Comment: ya, i visited this website and it is quite useful. thanks

Answer (score 4):

`.jpg` files can't have a transparent background. If you want the transparent background you have to use `.png` or `.svg` formatted file.